How to solve rigorously this complex functions question? (branch of complex Log)
We're given the following function $f(z)=\log_{a,b} ((z+1)^2)$ where $\log_{a,b}$ is for the branch of the complex Log where $a\leq \theta<b$.
We were asked to find $a,b$ such that the Holomorphic domain of $f(z)$ will be:
$$\mathbb{C}/\{z\in \mathbb{C}:Re(z)+1=-Im(z)\}$$
I don't know how to really do this rigorously, I've learned how to do it visually with the graph transformations, as in: I know that for the principal branch only the negative real number line is off limits, and if you do the same transformation presented in this question (i.e. taking $z$ shifting it by 1 and then squaring it) on the principal branch will be represented as the transformation from the negative real number line, to a line parallel to the Imaginary axis that the segment from y=1 to y=-1 is in the holomorphic domain and shifted by 1 to the left.
that means this transformation turns it by $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ (not sure which since the image is the same) and then shifts horizontally 1 unit to the left.
applying that same logic to the question I got that $a= -\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $b= \frac{3\pi}{2}$.
but as you can see my method isn't very reliable, I want to see the proper way to do it.

$\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$Set
$$A=\{z\in\mathbb C:\Re(z)+1=-\Im(z)\}.$$
Take $z=a+ib\in A$. The equation defining $A$ then tells us that $a+1=-b$, so we can write $z=-(b+1)+ib$. Then $z+1=b(i-1)$, so
$$(z+1)^2=b^2(i-1)^2=-2ib^2.$$
In particular $\Re((z+1)^2)=0$ and $\Im((z+1)^2)<0$, so if $z\in A$, then $(z+1)^2\in\{re^{\frac{3\pi}{2}i}:r>0\}$. This tells us that the branch cut for the logarithm should be at the negative imaginary axis, so $f$ should be
$$f(z)=\log_{-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}}((z+1)^2),$$
(or with $+2\pi n$ on the angles for any $n\in\mathbb Z$) which corresponds to what you found with your reasoning.

i kind of lost you in the middle, what you did is take a general z from set A and then find the real and imaginary part of said z when applying (z+1)^2, but after that I lost you.
why is $(z+1)^2\in {re^{\frac{3π}{2}i}:r>0}$?

@Nate3384 Think about what that set is. $e^{\frac{3\pi}{2}i}=-i$, so it's just the set with zero real part and negative imaginary part, which is the set we wanted

oh yes, I see now, thanks that makes sense to me.
